# I wish to optimize the code using pythonic ways using lambda and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, function, lambda

I have the following Dataframe:

```
TEST_NUMBER D1  D10 D50 D90 D99 Q3_15   Q3_10   l-Q3_63 RPM PRODUCT_NO
0   11  4.77    12.7    34.9    93.7    213.90  13.74   5.98    21.44   0.0 BQ0066
1   21  4.43    10.8    25.2    39.8    49.73   20.04   8.45    0.10    953.5   BQ0066
2   22  4.52    11.3    27.7    48.0    60.51   17.58   7.50    0.58    904.2   BQ0066
3   23  4.67    11.5    27.2    44.8    56.64   17.49   7.24    0.25    945.2   BQ0066
4   24  4.41    10.9    26.8    44.5    57.84   18.95   8.31    0.54    964.2   BQ0066
5   25  28.88   47.3    71.8    140.0   249.40  0.26    0.12    63.42   964.2   BQ0066
6   31  16.92   23.1    34.3    48.4    92.41   0.51    0.13    1.78    1694.5  BQ0066
7   32  16.35   22.2    33.0    45.8    59.14   0.53    0.11    0.64    1735.4  BQ0066
8   33  16.42   21.9    32.6    45.9    56.91   0.51    0.10    0.36    1754.4  BQ0066
9   34  3.47    7.3 14.1    20.7    26.52   56.59   23.71   0.00    1754.4  BQ0066
10  11  5.16    14.2    38.6    123.4   263.80  11.03   4.82    26.90   0.0 BQ0067
11  21  4.72    11.6    27.5    44.5    54.91   17.05   7.05    0.20    964.0   BQ0067
12  22  4.48    11.2    26.4    42.4    52.22   18.38   7.68    0.12    983.5   BQ0067
13  23  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 983.5   BQ0067
14  31  14.80   22.4    33.2    45.5    58.11   1.05    0.36    0.56    1753.4  BQ0067
15  32  16.30   22.1    32.1    44.7    55.12   0.57    0.13    0.23    1773.8  BQ0067
16  33  3.44    7.2 14.0    21.0    26.34   56.72   24.69   0.00    1773.8  BQ0067
17  11  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.0 BQ0068
18  21  4.83    11.9    28.1    44.2    54.63   16.76   6.70    0.19    953.7   BQ0068
19  22  4.40    10.7    26.3    43.4    57.55   19.85   8.59    0.53    974.9   BQ0068
20  23  17.61   43.8    67.9    122.6   221.20  0.75    0.33    58.27   974.9   BQ0068
21  31  15.09   22.3    33.3    45.6    59.45   0.98    0.38    0.73    1773.7  BQ0068
```

I wish to do the following things:
Steps:

1. Whenever the `TEST_NUMBER 11` is NaN(null values), I need to remove all rows of particular
   `PRODUCT_NO`. For example, in the given  dataframe, `PRODUCT_NO.` `BQ0068` has `TEST_NUMBER 11`
   with `NaN` values, hence all rows of `BQ0068` should be removed.
2. If any `TEST_NUMBER` other than `TEST_NUMBER 11` has `NaN` values, then only that particular
   `TEST_NUMBER's` row should be removed. For example, `PRODUCT_NO BQ0067` has row of `TEST_NUMBER 23` with `NaN` values. Hence only that particular row of `TEST_NUMBER 23`should be removed.
3. After doing the above steps, I need to the computation, for example, for `PRODUCT_NO BQ0066`, I
   need compute the the difference between rows in following way,
   `TEST_NUMBER 21` - `TEST_NUMBER 11`,  `TEST_NUMBER 22` - `TEST_NUMBER  11`, `TEST_NUMBER 23` - `TEST_NUMBER 11`,  `TEST_NUMBER 24` - `TEST_NUMBER 25`,
   `TEST_NUMBER 21` - `TEST_NUMBER 11`. And then `TEST_NUMBER 31` - `TEST_NUMBER 25`,
   `TEST_NUMBER 32` - `TEST_NUMBER 25`, `TEST_NUMBER 33` - `TEST_NUMBER 25`, `TEST_NUMBER 34` -
   `TEST_NUMBER 25`. And carry on the same procedure for successive `PRODUCT_NO`. As you can see
   `TEST_NUMBERS` frequency is different for each `PRODUCT_NO`. But in all cases, every
   `PRODUCT_NO`  will have only one `TEST_NUMBER 11` and the other TEST_NUMBERS will be in range
   of `21 to 29` i.e. `21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29` and `31, 32, 33 ,34, 35, 36, 37, 38,  39`

> PYTHON CODE

```
def pick_closest_sample(sample_list, sample_no):
    sample_list = sorted(sample_list)
    buffer = []
    for number in sample_list:
        if sample_no // 10 == number// 10:
            break
        else:
            buffer.append(number)
    if len(buffer) > 0:
        return buffer[-1]
    return sample_no


def add_closest_sample_df(df):
    unique_product_nos = list(df['PRODUCT_NO'].unique())
    out = []
    for product_no in unique_product_nos:
        subset = df[df['PRODUCT_NO'] == product_no]
        if subset.iloc[0].isnull().sum() == 0:
            subset.dropna(inplace = True)
            sample_list = subset['TEST_NUMBER'].to_list()
            subset['target_sample'] = subset['TEST_NUMBER'].apply(lambda x: pick_closest_sample(sample_list,x))
            out.append(subset)
        
    if len(out)>0:
        out = pd.concat(out)
        out.dropna(inplace=True)
    return out
```

> Output of above two functions:

```
    TEST_NUMBER D1  D10 D50 D90 D99 Q3_15   Q3_10   l-Q3_63 RPM PRODUCT_NO  target_sample
0   11  4.77    12.7    34.9    93.7    213.90  13.74   5.98    21.44   0.0 BQ0066  11
1   21  4.43    10.8    25.2    39.8    49.73   20.04   8.45    0.10    953.5   BQ0066  11
2   22  4.52    11.3    27.7    48.0    60.51   17.58   7.50    0.58    904.2   BQ0066  11
3   23  4.67    11.5    27.2    44.8    56.64   17.49   7.24    0.25    945.2   BQ0066  11
4   24  4.41    10.9    26.8    44.5    57.84   18.95   8.31    0.54    964.2   BQ0066  11
5   25  28.88   47.3    71.8    140.0   249.40  0.26    0.12    63.42   964.2   BQ0066  11
6   31  16.92   23.1    34.3    48.4    92.41   0.51    0.13    1.78    1694.5  BQ0066  25
7   32  16.35   22.2    33.0    45.8    59.14   0.53    0.11    0.64    1735.4  BQ0066  25
8   33  16.42   21.9    32.6    45.9    56.91   0.51    0.10    0.36    1754.4  BQ0066  25
9   34  3.47    7.3 14.1    20.7    26.52   56.59   23.71   0.00    1754.4  BQ0066  25
10  11  5.16    14.2    38.6    123.4   263.80  11.03   4.82    26.90   0.0 BQ0067  11
11  21  4.72    11.6    27.5    44.5    54.91   17.05   7.05    0.20    964.0   BQ0067  11
12  22  4.48    11.2    26.4    42.4    52.22   18.38   7.68    0.12    983.5   BQ0067  11
14  31  14.80   22.4    33.2    45.5    58.11   1.05    0.36    0.56    1753.4  BQ0067  22
15  32  16.30   22.1    32.1    44.7    55.12   0.57    0.13    0.23    1773.8  BQ0067  22
16  33  3.44    7.2 14.0    21.0    26.34   56.72   24.69   0.00    1773.8  BQ0067  22
```

As you can see, all rows of `PRODUCT_NO BQ0068` are removed as `TEST_NUMBER 11` had `NaN` values. Also only row of `TEST_NUMBER 23` of `PRODUCT_NO BQ0067` is removed as it had NaN values. So the requirements mentioned in the first two steps are met. Now the computation for `PRODUCT_NO BQ0067` will be like `TEST_NUMBER 31` - `TEST_NUMBER 22`, `TEST_NUMBER 32` - `TEST_NUMBER 22`, `TEST_NUMBER 33` - `TEST_NUMBER 22`

> PYTHON CODE

```
def compute_df(df):
    unique_product_nos = list(df['PRODUCT_NO'].unique())
    out = []
    for product_no in unique_product_nos:
        subset = df[df['PRODUCT_NO'] == product_no]
        target_list = list(subset['target_sample'].unique())
        for target in target_list:
            target_df = subset[subset['target_sample'] == target]
            target_subset = [subset[subset['TEST_NUMBER'] == target]]*len(target_df)
            target_subset = pd.concat(target_subset)
            if len(target_subset)> 0:
                
                target_subset.index = target_df.index
                diff_cols = ['D1','D10','D50','D90','D99','Q3_15','Q3_10','l-Q3_63','RPM']
        
                for col in diff_cols:
                    target_df[col + '_diff'] = target_df[col] - target_subset[col]
                out.append(target_df)
    if len(out)>0:
        out = pd.concat(out)
    return out
```

> Output of the above function:

```
TEST_NUMBER D1  D10 D50 D90 D99 Q3_15   Q3_10   l-Q3_63 RPM ... target_sample   D1_diff D10_diff    D50_diff    D90_diff    D99_diff    Q3_15_diff  Q3_10_diff  l-Q3_63_diff    RPM_diff
0   11  4.77    12.7    34.9    93.7    213.90  13.74   5.98    21.44   0.0 ... 11  0.00    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.0
1   21  4.43    10.8    25.2    39.8    49.73   20.04   8.45    0.10    953.5   ... 11  -0.34   -1.9    -9.7    -53.9   -164.17 6.30    2.47    -21.34  953.5
2   22  4.52    11.3    27.7    48.0    60.51   17.58   7.50    0.58    904.2   ... 11  -0.25   -1.4    -7.2    -45.7   -153.39 3.84    1.52    -20.86  904.2
3   23  4.67    11.5    27.2    44.8    56.64   17.49   7.24    0.25    945.2   ... 11  -0.10   -1.2    -7.7    -48.9   -157.26 3.75    1.26    -21.19  945.2
4   24  4.41    10.9    26.8    44.5    57.84   18.95   8.31    0.54    964.2   ... 11  -0.36   -1.8    -8.1    -49.2   -156.06 5.21    2.33    -20.90  964.2
5   25  28.88   47.3    71.8    140.0   249.40  0.26    0.12    63.42   964.2   ... 11  24.11   34.6    36.9    46.3    35.50   -13.48  -5.86   41.98   964.2
6   31  16.92   23.1    34.3    48.4    92.41   0.51    0.13    1.78    1694.5  ... 25  -11.96  -24.2   -37.5   -91.6   -156.99 0.25    0.01    -61.64  730.3
7   32  16.35   22.2    33.0    45.8    59.14   0.53    0.11    0.64    1735.4  ... 25  -12.53  -25.1   -38.8   -94.2   -190.26 0.27    -0.01   -62.78  771.2
8   33  16.42   21.9    32.6    45.9    56.91   0.51    0.10    0.36    1754.4  ... 25  -12.46  -25.4   -39.2   -94.1   -192.49 0.25    -0.02   -63.06  790.2
9   34  3.47    7.3 14.1    20.7    26.52   56.59   23.71   0.00    1754.4  ... 25  -25.41  -40.0   -57.7   -119.3  -222.88 56.33   23.59   -63.42  790.2
10  11  5.16    14.2    38.6    123.4   263.80  11.03   4.82    26.90   0.0 ... 11  0.00    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.0
11  21  4.72    11.6    27.5    44.5    54.91   17.05   7.05    0.20    964.0   ... 11  -0.44   -2.6    -11.1   -78.9   -208.89 6.02    2.23    -26.70  964.0
12  22  4.48    11.2    26.4    42.4    52.22   18.38   7.68    0.12    983.5   ... 11  -0.68   -3.0    -12.2   -81.0   -211.58 7.35    2.86    -26.78  983.5
14  31  14.80   22.4    33.2    45.5    58.11   1.05    0.36    0.56    1753.4  ... 22  10.32   11.2    6.8 3.1 5.89    -17.33  -7.32   0.44    769.9
15  32  16.30   22.1    32.1    44.7    55.12   0.57    0.13    0.23    1773.8  ... 22  11.82   10.9    5.7 2.3 2.90    -17.81  -7.55   0.11    790.3
16  33  3.44    7.2 14.0    21.0    26.34   56.72   24.69   0.00    1773.8  ... 22  -1.04   -4.0    -12.4   -21.4   -25.88  38.34   17.01   -0.12   790.3
```

Kindly help me optimize the code of three functions I posted, so I could write them in more pythonic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Points 1. and 2. can be achieved in a few line with pandas functions.
You can then calculate "target_sample" and your diff_col in the same loop using groupby:

```
# 1. Whenever TEST_NUMBER == 11 has D1 value NaN, remove all rows with this PRODUCT_NO
drop_prod_no = df[(df.TEST_NUMBER==11) & (df.D1.isna())]["PRODUCT_NO"]
df.drop(df[df.PRODUCT_NO.isin(drop_prod_no)].index, axis=0, inplace=True)

# 2. Drop remaining rows with NaN values
df.dropna(inplace=True)

# 3. set column "target_sample" and calculate diffs
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
diff_cols = ['D1','D10','D50','D90','D99','Q3_15','Q3_10','l-Q3_63','RPM']
for _, subset in df.groupby("PRODUCT_NO"):
    closest_sample = last_sample = 11
    for index, row in subset.iterrows():
        if row.TEST_NUMBER // 10 > closest_sample // 10 + 1:
            closest_sample = last_sample
        subset.at[index, "target_sample"] = closest_sample
        last_sample = row.TEST_NUMBER
        for col in diff_cols:
            subset.at[index, col + "_diff"] = subset.at[index, col] - float(subset[subset.TEST_NUMBER==closest_sample][col])
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, subset])

print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
    TEST_NUMBER     D1   D10   D50    D90     D99  Q3_15  Q3_10  l-Q3_63  ...  D1_diff D10_diff  D50_diff  D90_diff  D99_diff  Q3_15_diff  Q3_10_diff  l-Q3_63_diff  RPM_diff
0            11   4.77  12.7  34.9   93.7  213.90  13.74   5.98    21.44  ...     0.00      0.0       0.0       0.0      0.00        0.00        0.00          0.00       0.0
1            21   4.43  10.8  25.2   39.8   49.73  20.04   8.45     0.10  ...    -0.34     -1.9      -9.7     -53.9   -164.17        6.30        2.47        -21.34     953.5
2            22   4.52  11.3  27.7   48.0   60.51  17.58   7.50     0.58  ...    -0.25     -1.4      -7.2     -45.7   -153.39        3.84        1.52        -20.86     904.2
3            23   4.67  11.5  27.2   44.8   56.64  17.49   7.24     0.25  ...    -0.10     -1.2      -7.7     -48.9   -157.26        3.75        1.26        -21.19     945.2
4            24   4.41  10.9  26.8   44.5   57.84  18.95   8.31     0.54  ...    -0.36     -1.8      -8.1     -49.2   -156.06        5.21        2.33        -20.90     964.2
5            25  28.88  47.3  71.8  140.0  249.40   0.26   0.12    63.42  ...    24.11     34.6      36.9      46.3     35.50      -13.48       -5.86         41.98     964.2
6            31  16.92  23.1  34.3   48.4   92.41   0.51   0.13     1.78  ...   -11.96    -24.2     -37.5     -91.6   -156.99        0.25        0.01        -61.64     730.3
7            32  16.35  22.2  33.0   45.8   59.14   0.53   0.11     0.64  ...   -12.53    -25.1     -38.8     -94.2   -190.26        0.27       -0.01        -62.78     771.2
8            33  16.42  21.9  32.6   45.9   56.91   0.51   0.10     0.36  ...   -12.46    -25.4     -39.2     -94.1   -192.49        0.25       -0.02        -63.06     790.2
9            34   3.47   7.3  14.1   20.7   26.52  56.59  23.71     0.00  ...   -25.41    -40.0     -57.7    -119.3   -222.88       56.33       23.59        -63.42     790.2
10           11   5.16  14.2  38.6  123.4  263.80  11.03   4.82    26.90  ...     0.00      0.0       0.0       0.0      0.00        0.00        0.00          0.00       0.0
11           21   4.72  11.6  27.5   44.5   54.91  17.05   7.05     0.20  ...    -0.44     -2.6     -11.1     -78.9   -208.89        6.02        2.23        -26.70     964.0
12           22   4.48  11.2  26.4   42.4   52.22  18.38   7.68     0.12  ...    -0.68     -3.0     -12.2     -81.0   -211.58        7.35        2.86        -26.78     983.5
14           31  14.80  22.4  33.2   45.5   58.11   1.05   0.36     0.56  ...    10.32     11.2       6.8       3.1      5.89      -17.33       -7.32          0.44     769.9
15           32  16.30  22.1  32.1   44.7   55.12   0.57   0.13     0.23  ...    11.82     10.9       5.7       2.3      2.90      -17.81       -7.55          0.11     790.3
16           33   3.44   7.2  14.0   21.0   26.34  56.72  24.69     0.00  ...    -1.04     -4.0     -12.4     -21.4    -25.88       38.34       17.01         -0.12     79
```

Edit: you can avoid using `ìterrows` by applying lambda functions like you did:

```
# 3. set column "target_sample" and calculate diffs
def get_closest_sample(samples, test_no):
    closest_sample = last_sample = 11
    for smpl in samples:
        if smpl // 10 > closest_sample // 10 + 1:
            closest_sample = last_sample
        if smpl == test_no:
            break
        last_sample = smpl
    return closest_sample

new_df = pd.DataFrame()
diff_cols = ['D1','D10','D50','D90','D99','Q3_15','Q3_10','l-Q3_63','RPM']

for _, subset in df.groupby("PRODUCT_NO"):
    sample_list  = list(subset["TEST_NUMBER"])
    subset["target_sample"] = subset["TEST_NUMBER"].apply(lambda x: get_closest_sample(sample_list, x))
    for col in diff_cols:
        subset[col + "_diff"] = subset.apply(lambda row: row[col]-float(subset[subset.TEST_NUMBER==row["target_sample"]][col]), axis=1)
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, subset])

print(new_df)
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer first two lines of the code (Step 1 and Step 2) simply amazing. I would appreciate if you could give me the way other than iterrows() @Tranbi

Comment: I've updated my answer. I don't see any performance improvement though.